# lie down, lie to someone, corresponding noun?

Tags: grammar

A person who lies to others is called a 'liar'.

What is a person who couch-potatoes around (i.e. lies around) called?

Comment: A couch potato. _Liar_ is pre-emptive; there is no word *_lier_.

Comment: @JohnLawler why not in an answer?

Comment: [Both Collins and Webster's New World College Dictionary {4th edition}](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/lier) give the agent noun 'lier', as no doubt does the OED. But I'd say it's best avoided as very unidiomatic. However, this is general reference.

Comment: @Edwin OED says "This word belongs in Frequency Band 3. Band 3 contains words which occur between 0.01 and 0.1 times per million words in typical modern English usage. These words are not commonly found in general text types like novels and newspapers, but at the same they are not overly opaque or obscure. Nouns include *ebullition* and *merengue,* and examples of adjectives are *amortizable, prelapsarian, contumacious, agglutinative, quantized, argentiferous...*" So, not very common at all! (And I'm not sure that *merengue* is not overly opaque or obscure, either.)

Comment: The standard of english.stackexchange is way too high, this seems like a legit (albiet slighly humourous) question that experts can answer quickly. There is no need for 'extensive research' beforehand. Bye English stackexachange...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `lay about`. 
In some areas of the UK it’s common to say "I was laying there on the couch", in the same sort of context as "And now I lay me down to sleep". This is probably a colloquialism, though, as I’ve seen it on Internet forums but not formal literature.
The Oxford English Dictionary gives one of the definitions as past tense of lie:
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lay

Comment: Lay about is exactly right. Well done @Pam, although somebody seems not to like it but has not troubled to explain why.

Comment: Thanks @JeremyC. Ironically the words "outlier" and "inlier" (statistics and graphs) also occurred to me last night, so maybe "lier" is some sort of noun.